# Add confirm upon release event to a custom shortcut

Tags: scripting, customization, shortcut

I've changed shortcut for pan 3D view to spacebar + mouse movement and it works fine because at the bottom of the shortcut edit window there's a View3D Move Modal section that allowed me to tell Blender to confirm (stop panning) upon releasing spacebar.

I'm trying to do the same for 2D view (node editor). I could set spacebar + mouse movement for panning but there isn't a View3D Move Modal section there.. when I release spacebar panning doesn't stop. When I hit Esc it does stop.

How can I configure the same behavior for 2D view as I could configure for 3D? I only have basic knowledge of changing shortcuts but no python scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand I've been overthinking this while the solution is simply to set spacebar for panning both in 2D view and 3D view.

For some reason I thought in the 3D view/pan view window I needed to set mouse movement, then spacebar as a modifier and then in the view3D Move Modal section in the bottom also set confirm: spacebar: release to make it work the right way (see image with my overcomplicated setup) It did work but was unnecessary complicated and could not be applied for 2D view.

[image: Keyboard Shortcut Setup]